# Query And Join Multiple Column on MySql

Tags: mysql, join, multivalue-database

I have two table with big data in our MySQL database.

tbl_phonebook :

```
 PB_ID    CUST_NAME     PHONE1     PHONE2      PHONE3     PHONE4
 1        Richard       11111      12222       13333      14444
 2        Maria         21111      22222       23333      24444
 3        Robert        31111      32222       33333      34444
```

tbl_calllog :

```
 LOG_ID   CALL_TIME     PHONENUMBER   
 1        2020-06-01    22222       
 2        2020-06-01    55555
 3        2020-06-01    13333
```

How to get result like this with best performance :

```
 LOG_ID   CALL_TIME     PHONENUMBER   CUST_NAME
 1        2020-06-01    22222         Maria
 2        2020-06-01    55555         -
 3        2020-06-01    13333         Richard
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you could change your table structure to not have columns like phone1, phone2, phone3, phone4 that would be better. In that way you could manage your data well and operate queries much easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this query:

```
select 
  c.LOG_ID, c.CALL_TIME, c.PHONENUMBER, p.CUST_NAME 
from 
  tbl_calllog c 
left join 
  tbl_phonebook p 
on 
  c.PHONENUMBER in (p.PHONE1, p.PHONE2, p.PHONE3, p.PHONE4);
```

I'm afaid current query is not the best performance, because mysql have to check conditions in all phone columns.

Setup a new table to map phone number to user like the following:

```
create table tbl_phonebook (
  `PB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CUST_NAME` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PHONE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PB_ID`),
  index idx_p1 (PHONE)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
insert into tbl_phonebook2 (CUST_NAME, PHONE)
VALUES ('Richard', 11111),
       ('Richard', 12222),
       ('Richard', 13333),
       ('Richard', 14444),
       ('Maria', 21111),
       ('Maria', 22222),
       ('Maria', 23333),
       ('Maria', 24444),
       ('Robert', 31111),
       ('Robert', 32222),
       ('Robert', 33333),
       ('Robert', 34444);
```

query will be:

```
select
       c.LOG_ID, c.CALL_TIME, c.PHONENUMBER, p.CUST_NAME
from
     tbl_calllog c
left join
    tbl_phonebook2 p
on c.PHONENUMBER = p.PHONE;
```

the result and execution plan are as following:

```
mysql> select
    ->        c.LOG_ID, c.CALL_TIME, c.PHONENUMBER, p.CUST_NAME
    -> from
    ->      tbl_calllog c
    -> left join
    ->     tbl_phonebook2 p
    -> on c.PHONENUMBER = p.PHONE;
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| LOG_ID | CALL_TIME  | PHONENUMBER | CUST_NAME |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|      1 | 2020-06-01 |       22222 | Maria     |
|      2 | 2020-06-01 |       55555 | NULL      |
|      3 | 2020-06-01 |       13333 | Richard   |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select
    ->        c.LOG_ID, c.CALL_TIME, c.PHONENUMBER, p.CUST_NAME
    -> from
    ->      tbl_calllog c
    -> left join
    ->     tbl_phonebook2 p
    -> on c.PHONENUMBER = p.PHONE;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL   | NULL    | NULL               |    3 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | ref  | idx_p1        | idx_p1 | 5       | test.c.PHONENUMBER |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hi Zhiyong, you are right, change table structure is best way ☺.  I'll do that if have authority to change this "fat table". Your answer very detail,  many people will refer to your explanation. Thanks 

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept my answer later if it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to append `Cust_Name` to your call table... so a left join onto the call table will suffice:

```
SELECT tcl.*,
       tpb.Cust_Name
FROM tbl_calllog tcl
LEFT JOIN tbl_phonebook tpb ON (tcl.phonenumber = tpb.phone1
                                OR tcl.phonenumber = tpb.phone2
                                OR tcl.phonenumber = tpb.phone3
                                OR tcl.phonenumber = tpb.phone4)
```

**Note:** If the phone numbers in tbl_phonebook are not unique you'll need to look at an alternative join.

Comment: I read a discus in a sql forum, "OR" is "killer performance". What your opinion?